# Google Apps Script - How to insert table into existing TableCell

Tags: google-apps-script

Into the below code commented code is running fine but the same insertTable is giving an error **Service unavailable: Docs**

```
function createTbl(){
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

  // Create a two-dimensional array containing the cell contents.
  var cells = [
   ['Row 1, Cell 1', 'Row 1, Cell 2'],
   ['Row 2, Cell 1', 'Row 2, Cell 2']
  ];

  var tbl = body.appendTable(cells);
  var row = tbl.getChild(0);
  var cell = row.getChild(0);

  //cell.insertParagraph(0,'Hello Wrold!'));
  cell.insertTable(0,cells)  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Apps Script that pops up whenever a script tries to add a subtable to a TableCell.

See the [issue in the Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=894).